# CustomAdapter show duplicate Item with SQL Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have one problem here, I added names and rates of the 2 different coffee shop to the database, but when I showed them to the custom listview it's totally failed, the listview showed 2 columns with the same name of coffee shops, but when I tried to use normal ArrayAdapter to show only the name and it's totally good. I don't know what's wrong in here.
Thanks for your help.

Code that I used to retrieve the data

```
public ArrayList<UserReview> searchAllReview(String name) {
        ArrayList<UserReview> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.clear();

        searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM detail3 where establish= '"+ name+ "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(searchQuery, null);
        UserReview userReview = new UserReview();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userReview.name=cursor.getString(0);
                userReview.rate=cursor.getFloat(3);
                al.add(userReview);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return al;
    }
```

This is when I click search :

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                db = new UserDBHandling(getApplicationContext());
                List<Float> m = db.getRating(estab);
                float max = Collections.max(m);
                if(radioButtonAll.isChecked()) {
                    list = db.searchAllReview(estab);
                }
                else if(radioButtonBest.isChecked()){
                    list = db.searchBestReview(max, estab);
                }
                customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_user_search , list);
//                aa = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext() , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , list);
                listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                index = position;
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And this is Custom Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;
    int resource;
    List<UserReview> objects;
    public CustomAdapter( Context context, int resource,  List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource=resource;
        this.objects=objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {

       MyElements myElements;
       if(convertView ==null){
           myElements = new MyElements();

           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource , parent , false);
           myElements.text = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewUser);
           myElements.rate=convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingUser);

       }else {
           myElements=(MyElements)convertView.getTag();
       }
       UserReview userReview = objects.get(position);
       myElements.text.setText(userReview.name);
       myElements.rate.setRating(userReview.rate);
       myElements.rate.setClickable(false);

      return convertView;
    }
public class MyElements{
        TextView text;
        RatingBar rate;
}
```

Comment: remove the `do-while`

Comment: It only shows 1 coffee shop :(

Comment: place `UserReview userReview = new UserReview();` after if `(cursor.moveToFirst())`.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
UserReview userReview = new UserReview();
```

must be inside the loop, because you want a new object for each row of the table:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        UserReview userReview = new UserReview();
        userReview.name=cursor.getString(0);
        userReview.rate=cursor.getFloat(3);
        al.add(userReview);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Also (not related) use this method of passing parameters to the `rawQuery()` method:

```
searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM detail3 where establish = ?";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(searchQuery, new String[] {name});
```

This way you avoid the risk of [`sql injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in your queries. 
And before the `return` statement don't forget to close the database objects:

```
cursor.close();
db.close();
```

Comment: @HảiTôHoàng if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.